# Multiple static files directories

Tags: go

In go, we can handle static files, by defining their directory as static directory as shown below:

```golang
        fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/")) 
        http.Handle("/files/", fs)
```

Where static files folder `static` should be beside the binary.

Another way, is to use the new `//go embed` as:

```golang
        //go:embed static
        var staticFiles embed.FS

        // http.FS can be used to create a http Filesystem
        var staticFS = http.FS(staticFiles)
        fs := http.FileServer(staticFS) // embeded static files
        // Serve static files
        http.Handle("/static/", fs)
```

But what if I want to have most of my static files embedded in the binary, and some are not, that can be used alongside the binary, I tried to mix both method defined above, but did not work, only the `embedded` ones run smoothly, below code failed, any thought?:

```golang
        //go:embed static
        var staticFiles embed.FS

        // http.FS can be used to create a http Filesystem
        var staticFS = http.FS(staticFiles)
        fs := http.FileServer(staticFS) // embeded static files
        // Serve static files
        http.Handle("/static/", fs)

        www := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./files/")) // side static files, to be beside binary
        // Serve static files
        http.Handle("/files/", www)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, was missing `http.StripPrefix`, below worked perfectly with me, and have multiple static folders:

```golang
package main

import (
    "embed"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

//go:embed static
var staticFiles embed.FS

func main() {
    go func() {
        http.HandleFunc("/favicon.ico", func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {})
        // http.FS can be used to create a http Filesystem
        var staticFS = http.FS(staticFiles)
        fs := http.FileServer(staticFS) // embeded static files
        // Serve static files, to be embedded in the binary
        http.Handle("/static/", fs)

        // Serve public files, to be beside binary
        http.Handle("/public/", http.StripPrefix("/public/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./files"))))

        http.HandleFunc("/getSkills", getSkills)
        log.Println("Listening on :3000...")
        err := http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
}
```